# PHP MySQL utf-8 Euro symbol shown as questionmark on a diamond

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, utf-8, euro

So after a whole day of googling and debugging I end up here.

## MySQL

set to the following encoding:

```
db:  utf8_general_ci
table: utf8_general_ci
column: utf8_general_ci, TEXT
```

I put in some euro symbols and some other weird characters

> acentuação €€€€€

## PHP (codeigniter)

config

```
$config['charset'] = 'UTF-8';
```

dsn

```
char_set=utf8,dbcollat=utf8_general_ci
```

I made some queries to compare

#### model

```
$query = $this->db->query("SET NAMES latin1");
$query = $this->db->query("SELECT shortdesc,HEX(shortdesc) FROM `contracttypes` WHERE id = 4");
$ret['latin1'] =  $query->row();
$query = $this->db->query("SET NAMES utf8");
$query = $this->db->query("SELECT shortdesc,HEX(shortdesc) FROM `contracttypes` WHERE id = 4");
$ret['utf8'] =  $query->row();
return $ret;;
```

#### controller

```
public function utfhell()  {
var_dump($this->campagne_model->utfhell());
}
```

This outputs

```
array (size=2)
'latin1' => 
object(stdClass)[34]
public 'shortdesc' => string 'acentua��o �����' (length=16)
public 'HEX(shortdesc)' => string '6163656E747561C3A7C3A36F20E282ACE282ACE282ACE282ACE282AC' (length=56)
'utf8' => 
object(stdClass)[33]
public 'shortdesc' => string 'acentuação €€€€€' (length=28)
public 'HEX(shortdesc)' => string '6163656E747561C3A7C3A36F20E282ACE282ACE282ACE282ACE282AC' (length=56)
```

So far so good, on to a

## view

```
<?php header('Content-Type: text/html; charset="utf-8"', true); ?>
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<title>UTFhell</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../assets/css/style.css"/>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8">
...
<?php
echo 'Original : ', $campagne_info->contractName->shortdesc."<br />";
echo 'UTF8 Encode : ', utf8_encode($campagne_info->contractName->shortdesc)."<br />";
echo 'UTF8 Decode : ', utf8_decode($campagne_info->contractName->shortdesc)."<br />";
echo 'TRANSLIT : ', iconv("ISO-8859-1", "UTF-8//TRANSLIT", $campagne_info->contractName->shortdesc)."<br />";
echo 'IGNORE TRANSLIT : ', iconv("ISO-8859-1", "UTF-8//IGNORE//TRANSLIT", $campagne_info->contractName->shortdesc)."<br />";
echo 'IGNORE   : ', iconv("ISO-8859-1", "UTF-8//IGNORE", $campagne_info->contractName->shortdesc)."<br />";
echo 'Plain: ', iconv("ISO-8859-1", "UTF-8", $campagne_info->contractName->shortdesc)."<br />";
echo '€€€€€€€€€€<br>'; 
?>
```

None of these now show me a normal euro symbol except the final echo statement, they all give me questionmark diamonds for the eurosymbols

Comment: store them in DB with base64_encode() and use them with base64_decode

Comment: What do you get when you run your query in a MySQL editor or phpmyadmin ? SELECT shortdesc,HEX(shortdesc) FROM `contracttypes` WHERE id = 4

Comment: I get
shortdesc  HEX(shortdesc)  
acentuação €€€€€ 6163656E747561C3A7C3A36F20E282ACE282ACE282ACE282ACE282AC
So that works

Comment: Which CI version and database driver are you using?

Comment: CodeIgniter 3.0.0 and PDO mysql

Comment: Actually, since you see it correctly in the `var_dump()` output, that's irrelevant ... sorry. Other than `$campagne_info->contractName->shortdesc` not being quite the same as what you have in your `utfhell()` method, I don't see why it could go wrong.

Comment: It comes down to the same, Maybe this is a HTML or apache issue

Comment: Did you saved the file with UTF8 encoding?

Comment: Yes saved the view as utf8 with atom. maybe the index.php is different. should that be utf8 as well?

Comment: So I put $this->db->query("SET NAMES utf8"); in my model contructor. That works. Why isnt CI pdo mysql doing what its supposed to and do that for me?

Answer (score 1):

The **HEX** is the utf8 encoding for that string.  So the data is in the table 'correctly'.

**The black diamond** (�) is the browser's way of saying wtf.  It comes from having latin1 characters, but telling the browser
to display utf8 characters.

You *could* tell the browser to display "Western", that is avoiding the underlying problems.
Remember, the goal is to really use utf8.

Sometimes this occurs together with Question Marks, in which case you must start over.

**The cause (probably):**

1. The bytes you had were encoded latin1.  You acquired them from somewhere -- file dump online input, etc.
2. The connection parameters said latin1.
3. The column/table is declared to be CHARACTER SET said utf8, so during INSERT, they were correctly converted.
4. When SELECTing, the seting in step 2 was again latin1, so they were converted back to latin1.
5. When displaying text in a web page, the page's header said that the bytes were utf8.

**Solution, Plan A:**  (Sloppy, but probably workable)

Change #5 so say the appropriate equivalent of latin1.

**Solution, Plan B:**

1. Fix the source to be utf8-encoded
2. `query("SET NAMES utf8")` (unless there is a way to set it at connect time)
3. Leave the table/column at `CHARACTER SET utf8`
4. Step 2 cover this.
5. Leave `<meta ... UTF-*>`.